# How to use multiple references in OpenAPI 3 yaml file's paths section?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I try to organize my one giant OpenAPI yaml file into several small pieces and then bundle it with `swagger-cli`. And I run into the paths section.

This is my `openapi.yml` file now:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  description: Multi-file boilerplate for OpenAPI Specification.
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://example.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /blog:
    $ref: './routes/blog/create-getall.yml'
  /blog/{id}:
    $ref: './routes/blog/show-update-delete.yml'
```

Now the problem is I want to separate `create-getall.yml` file into `create.yml` and `get-all.yml`, and I want to split `show-update-delete.yml` file into `show.yml`, `update.yml` and `delete.yml` files.

But after I do this split, I try to use files as reference like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /blog:
    $ref: './routes/blog/create.yml'
    $ref: './routes/blog/get-all.yml'
  /blog/{id}:
    $ref: './routes/blog/with-id.yml'
```

And I get `Map keys must be unique` error message.

If I try `$ref1`, `$ref2` and similar, then I get `Property $ref1 is not allowed` error.

I tried to use `allOf`, but it leads to `Property allOf is not allowed.` error.

The `create.yml` file is this:

```yaml
post:
  tags:
  - blog
  summary: create a blog post
  description: |
    You can create a new blog post.
  parameters:
  - in: body
    name: content
    schema:
      $ref: 'Post.yml'
  responses:
    200:
      description: new item's ID
```

So how can I use these splitted files in `paths` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification does not have a way to use multiple $refs under a single path. There's an existing feature request to [allow $refs on the operation level](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2922) which, if implemented, would support your scenario.